# Container lockdown

Tags: lxc, container

I was reading about LXC vs OpenVZ and was wondering if this issue has already been solved in more recent updates:

> OpenVZ has done quite a good job at this, but LXC still has issues
>   here. Even with AppArmor enabled, in Ubuntu you still have access to
>   dmesg from the guests and /proc/kcore and /proc/sysrq-trigger are
>   still accessible, so a root user in a guest VM could easily restart
>   the host machine. Improvements are planned for Ubuntu version 13.04.

source: http://www.janoszen.com/2013/01/22/lxc-vs-openvz/

Answer (score 2):

By using `echo 1 > /proc/sys/kernel/dmesg_restrict` you can restrict the `dmesg` access to the root user of the host. Other users including the root user in the LXC have then no access.

Comment: This does not seem to work with linux 3.16.0 here. The setting is there, it is set to 1 afterwards, but the LXC-containers still show the dmesg output.

Comment: @allo This works probably only for unprivileged container.

Comment: Ah, that makes sense. Still a problem, because other containers are isolating this better.

Answer (score 1):

To disable access to /proc/kcore:

```
lxc.cap.drop = sys_rawio
```

To disable access to dmesg load following file using `lxc.seccomp` option:

```
2
blacklist
[all]
syslog errno 1
```

Works fine for me on LXC-1.0.6, kernel 4.3.0.